# Utilizar IN ou múltiplos OR? Qual possui melhor performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, query, desempenho

Tenho as seguintes consultas no MySQL:

1º: Utilizando múltiplos `OR`

```
 SELECT SUM(qtd)
    FROM 
        produtos
    WHERE 
        qtd > 10 
        and (status = '0' or status = '4' or status = '7')
```

2º: Utilizando `IN`

```
 SELECT SUM(qtd)
    FROM 
        produtos
    WHERE 
        qtd > 10 
        and status IN (0,4,7)
```

Qual consulta terá melhor performance? Ambos irão me resultar os mesmos dados ou tem diferença?

Comment: Segue: (necessita de tradução) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `IN` é uma implementação interna e pode ser melhor otimizada. Não deve ter ganho grande, mas é para ser mais rápida para uma lista grande de comparação.

Mas em geral a escolha deve ser em função da semântica e não pela performance. O `IN` procura por um valor em um conjunto de dados, o `OR` concatena condições e só vale o uso se for em pequena quantidade. Para pequena quantidade a performance não fará diferença. Para grande volume de comparação o `OR` é virtualmente inviável.

O `IN` é mais poderoso por poder comprar com um conjunto de dados a ser determinado.

Quando não faz diferença qual usar, escolha uma forma e seja sempre consistente.