# Como fazer Update em 3 linhas em uma query

Tags: sql-server

Como consigo fazer um update para alterar o valor de 3 linhas?

Tenho uma estrutura parecida:

```
Id |             Nome                   | Ordinal
13 | Juizado Especial Cível             |    ª
14 | Juizado Especial Criminal          |    ª
15 | Juizado Especial Cível e Criminal  |    ª
```

Preciso alterar a ordinal de 'ª' para 'º' dos ids 13, 14 e 15 em uma única query, ao invez de fazer um update para cada id.

Como faço?

Muito obrigado.

Comment: `UPDATE tabela SET campo = valor WHERE id IN (13,14,15)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples usa-se o update com o **WHERE** com quantas condições forem necessárias usando operadores relacionais nesse caso o **OR**

```
UPDATE table1 SET Ordinal = 'º' WHERE id = 13 OR id = 14 OR 15
```

Ou usa-se o **IN** que segue no mesmo raciocínio:

```
UPDATE table1 SET Ordinal = 'º' WHERE id IN (13,14,15)
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/218462/57801

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo, estava fazendo com 'and' ao invés de 'or' e não estava funcionando, agora foi certo!

Comment: Poderia colocar minha resposta como a resposta aceita então??? Muito obrigado.... cuidado com o "and" e o "or" confunde mesmo

Answer (score 2):

## Cabeçalhos

use in() na sua cláusula where, exemplo:

```
UPDATE table1 SET Ordinal = 'º' WHERE id IN (13,14,15),
```

Ref:https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado!